# How to get the total count of Instances and volumes and loadbalancers present in the aws using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I need to get the total counts from aws console using boto3
I tried to display instances and volumes list but not counts.

I want to know how to list all resources present with the counts.

Can anyone please guide me on this.

```
 for region in ec2_regions:
 conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
               region_name=region)
instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running','stopped']}])

for instance in instances:
    #if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
        print (instance.id, instance.instance_type, region)


volumes = conn.volumes.filter()

for vol in volumes:
    print(vol.id,vol.volume_type,region,vol.size)
```

I want to get the Total count of each resource.
I tried len, size, and other available keys for getting the count but in vain.

Comment: Does the above code work (does it print instance id and volume id respectively)? What did you try with len or size? Can you share that code?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004, Yes the code works and print the available resources from available regions. 
I just tried to print len(instance)
I tried count =1 and for loop but getting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects returned by `filter()` are of type `boto3.resources.collection.ec2.instancesCollection` and don't have the `__len__` method that the `len()` function needs. Couple of different solutions come to mind:

- Create a list from the collection, and use that. E.g., `my_list = [instance for instance in instances]; len(my_list)`. This is what I typically do.
- Use the `enumerate` function, with a start value of 1. E.g., `for i, instance in enumerate(instances, start=1): pass`. After the last iteration, `i` will essentially be the count.

Comment: Or shorter with a list comprehension: `len([instance for instance in instances])`